# Local database connection

Tags: database, vb.net, local

In a windows desktop application (with vb.net and wpf), i store some data in xml file, located in appdata folder. If the xml file does not exists, application creates it with a specific format. My data is becoming more complex, and i want to use a mysql database. So what i want:

1) Have a local mysql database in a user folder (Appdata). It should be created run time if it does not exists. It should be created programatically run-time.

2) I want to know compatibility with .net and windows versions. (sdf, mdb files?)

Any help? I will provide some code based on answers. Thanks.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is based on Windows operating system then you can go with Microsoft Office Access Database. You just need to install MDAC and some library to use access database file using visual studio. Access Database can be supported over the Local Area Network also. You can connect access database file using **OleDB.Connection** object in .net. You can find the basic example of access database connectivity using vb.net [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_database_access.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am trying to create the database programmatically with ADOX but i got (Class not registered at ADOX.CatalogClass.Create) error. Question is: Should i create database programmatically, or is there a way (and is better) to distribute it in my exe file? Link says how to connect to database.

Comment: You can create empty database and place it into local resources that will be copied when you installing your application in any machine. You can find out the tutorial to create access database using ADOX [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317881)